# Asynchronous delegates: performance in modern .NET world

Tags: c#, asynchronous

There is a legacy project. There are a lof of Asynchronous delegates and code like this:

```
IAsyncResult result = startDelegate.BeginInvoke(param1,
                param2,
                new AsyncCallback(CallbackMethod),
                null);
```

or just completely parameterless calls
like

```
IAsyncResult result = startDelegate.BeginInvoke(CallbackMethod,null);
```

The main purpose of desired refactoring is: performance. Many places in the project has been optimized a lot and now it's time for async stuff.
From performance point of view: is there any sense to migrate from Async delegates calls to:

1. ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem for parametless calls
2. BackgroundWorker to report progres to GUI (now GUI subcribes to events in async code)
3. Rewrite some parts to async await?

so, general question: how bad (or not bad) from performance point of view Async delegates in compare with 1)-3) above?

Comment: "The main purpose of desired refactoring is: performance." Does that mean you've already instrumented your application to *measure* the performance in every way you care about? Do you have concrete performance targets for the refactoring so you know when you'll be "done"? I'd personally be somewhat surprised to see this actually make a significant difference - but if you haven't got the measurements in place, you'll never know. (Personally I think the more important reason for refactoring towards async/await is usually readability and maintainability...)

Comment: @JonSkeet we use dotTrace to record application activity and then analyze its report to find bottlenecks. A lot of stuff related to DB/interaction between Layers in the app has been optimized by using these reports. The only place what is not touched yet: async stuff.  There is confusion: how to correctly measure it and should we use more modern approaches?  may be there is already good tests on github that compares different async approaches in .NET world from performance point of view? I am not sure  I'm able to write good test to compare them

Comment: Put it this way: if you don't have enough of a performance problem that you'd be able to tell the difference, do you really have a performance problem? (Try to measure meaningful times rather than micro-benchmarking. Set concrete requirements in terms of response times etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The main purpose of desired refactoring is: performance.

You almost certainly won't see noticeable performance gains from changing this. However, there are two major benefits for replacing `Delegate.BeginInvoke` calls:

1. Maintainability. `async`/`await` is the style of asynchronous programming that is most maintainable.
2. Portability. Last I checked, .NET Core doesn't support `Delegate.BeginInvoke`, so if you ever move from .NET Desktop Framework to .NET Core, you'll need to change this code. Side note: there are some pretty good performance benefits just from migrating to .NET Core.

If you do choose to remove the calls to `BeginInvoke`, I recommend using `Task.Run`. It's a modern solution.

Comment: _"Portability. Last I checked, .NET Core doesn't support Delegate.BeginInvoke"_ well... this is some sort of critical point for us because in the end of February-beginning of the March we are going to start transition to .NET 7.

Comment: _"If you do choose to remove the calls to BeginInvoke, I recommend using Task.Run. It's a modern solution."_ for long running operation it is OK, and what is modern solution for reporting GUI about progress etc &? Should I use Progress<T> or so?

Comment: @JhonMalk199: Yes, `IProgress<T>` is the modern approach. I have a [series of blog posts](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-intro.html) on `Task.Run` vs `BackgroundWorker` that demonstrates how to different things with `Task.Run` in a UI app (just ignore the BGW parts).